# saving data from external file into a list using python

Tags: python, linux

The question may sound repeated; but here is the code which will explain the question:

```
#compares partitions displayed by 'df' command with the required list of partitions.

import subprocess
import re


p = subprocess.Popen("df -h", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
dfdata, _ = p.communicate()

dfdata = dfdata.replace("Mounted on", "")

columns = [list() for i in range(10)]
for line in dfdata.split("\n"):
    line = re.sub(" +", " ", line)
    for i,l in enumerate(line.split(" ")):
        columns[i].append(l)


sys_partition = columns[5]
req_partition = ['/', '/boot', '/home', '/usr', '/usr/local', '/var', '/tmp', '/mnt/floppy', '/mnt/cdrom', '/dev/shm']


def remove_common_elements(sys_partition, req_partition):
    sys_partition_new = sys_partition[:]
    req_partition_new = req_partition[:]

    for i in sys_partition:
        if i in req_partition_new:
            sys_partition_new.remove(i)
            req_partition_new.remove(i)
return req_partition_new

if set(sys_partition) == set(req_partition):
    print 'All the partitions exist in your system!!!'
else:
    print 'These partitions do not exist: ',
    print (remove_common_elements(sys_partition, req_partition))
```

In this program, 'sys_partition' implies partitions present int the system(shown by df command) and 'req_partition' implies the list of partitions which should be ideally present. Now, I don't want to hardcode the required partitions (req_partition). I want to take that input from some external file and store it into a list and then process it like shown. 
Please help. If the question is confusing, I will try to elaborate more.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are asking how to read from a file, and put the items in a list. If so, remove this line:

```
req_partition = ['/', '/boot', '/home', '/usr', '/usr/local', '/var', '/tmp',    '/mnt/floppy', '/mnt/cdrom', '/dev/shm']
```

Replace it with these lines:

```
req_partition = list()
with open('/path/to/partitions') as f:
    for line in f:
        req_partition.append(line.strip())
```

And ensure the file, `/path/to/partitions`, has these contents:

```
/
/boot
/home
/usr
/usr/local
/var
/tmp
/mnt/floppy
/mnt/cdrom
/dev/shm
```